# Php script only inserting 5000 rows into a phpMyAdmin database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following script that I wrote:

```
<?php

$filename = "readingDataFromThis.LOG";
$filterarray= array("stuff to remove from the file", "and more stuff");
if (file_exists($filename) && is_readable ($filename)) {
    ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
    $con=mysqli_connect("server","username","password","database_name");
    $count = 0;

    $fh = fopen($filename, "r");
    if ($fh) {
        while (($line =  fgets($fh)) != false) {

            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }
            if (strpos_arr($line, $filterarray) == false) {
                $month = substr($line, 3,5);
                $day = substr($line, 0,2);
                $year = substr($line, 6,8);
                $timestamp = substr($line, 9, 17);
                $message = substr($line, 18);

                mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Conversation (Month, Day, Year, Time, Message)
                VALUES ('$month', '$day', '$year', '$timestamp', '$message')");
                echo "Inserted record " . $count++ . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($fh);
    mysqli_close($con);
    echo "Complete.";
}

function strpos_arr($haystack, $needle) {
    if(!is_array($needle)) $needle = array($needle);
    foreach($needle as $what) {
        if(($pos = strpos($haystack, $what))!==false) return $pos;
    }
    return false;
}
?>
```

When I run it, I have no issues, the output I receive on the screen essentially looks like:

```
Inserted record 0
Inserted record 1
...
Inserted record 14000+
Complete.
```

However, when I go to the table in the database itself, I find that only EXACTLY the first 5000 records inserted into the database.  What is happening here?

Comment: `phpMyAdmin` has a limit on the number of rows it will show at once. Are you sure that's not what you're running into? What does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Conversation` show?

Comment: SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM Conversation
 > Returns > 
COUNT(*)
5000

---- So, I inserted a single record manually, and I can see 5,001 records from my primary table view.

Comment: Do any of the columns have unique indexes? You may have duplicates.

Comment: Add error checking. You can also call `mysqli_affected_rows($con)` after each `INSERT` to find out if it added anything.

Comment: The source file being parsed is a conversation log from a game.  Each line is a Date and timestamp followed by a player and message.  The only possibility of a duplicate would be a player stating the exact same thing repeatedly (i.e. spam).

Comment: Since yuo're not using `mysqli_bind_param()`, you need to call `mysqli_real_escape_string` on the message, in case it contains quotes that produce invalid syntax.

Comment: After adding the affected_rows error checking, I now see any line which contains a ' is being unaffected.  I do not believe this is the full issue as towards the end theres still thousands of lines behaving this way, but I may have to work on a solution to how to handle the ' first.

Comment: That's exactly what my answer solves.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60133/discussion-between-cuckoo-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, substr($line, 18));
```

to ensure that the message can be substituted into the query properly. Otherwise, if `$message` contains a quote character, you get invalid SQL syntax when it gets subtituted into the query.

It would be better to recode using `mysqli_prepare()` and `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that they are duplicated on your Key, thus, not inserted or are updating previous values.
If it is taking too long, it could simply be timing out. PHPMyAdmin however has a feature that will stop execution if the timeout is about to be reached - which also means that it will allow you to resume from the right place.

Comment: If it were timing out, how would it print out all the `Inserted record  N` lines? And he already said in a comment that there's no duplicate data.

Comment: He's not using PHPMyAdmin to do the inserts, he's using a PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

Working with Barmar in a discussion, we ended up modifying the following lines of code:

```
    $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,substr($line, 18));
```

This essentially handles the strange lines of text which have characters such as ' in them which will break the syntax for the SQL INSERT statement.

```
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Conversation (Month, Day, Year, Time, Message)
    VALUES ('$month', '$day', '$year', '$timestamp', '$message')") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

In this block of code, we added the **or die(mysqli_error($con));**

This tells the program to halt execution and output an error as to why.  This provided me with the following error:

User 'my_sa' has exceeded the 'max_updates' resource (current value: 5000)

I am using a free web host, so based on some google searches, we determined it is likely a rate limit issue and can be resolved by running the programs in iterations to insert a section of records at a time.